# Matching elements within list in R

Tags: regex, r, list, match

Imagine that I have a list, defined below:

```
test <- list(1:4,5,8,1,2:3,10)
```

I would like to somehow match elements of the list if they contain any similar numbers.  For example I would like to match `test[[1]]` and `test[[4]]` because they both contain a 1.  Likewise, `test[[1]]` and `test[[5]]` would also match because they both contain 2 and 3.

After matching, I would like to construct a unique id which corresponds to each match.  For example the answer would be the following list

```
ans <- list(1,2,3,1,1,4)
```

*EDIT:*
*The intuition behind this answer is that if the elements of the list `test` share a common match, they receive the same id.  This means that even though `test[[4]]` and `test[[5]]` don't match, the fact that they each match `test[[1]]` means that they will be assigned the same id.*

This is obviously a toy example.  In practice I would like to apply this matching to a large list (>100,000k elements).  With that in mind the algorithm will need to be somewhat efficient.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Hot do you get the last three values `1,1,4`?

Comment: RStudent, does it make more sense now?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's one way using `data.table`:

```
require(data.table)
# generate a data.table from your data
id = rep(seq_along(test), sapply(test, length))
dt = data.table(id, val = unlist(test))
# solution
dt[, ans := id[1L], by=val][, ans := .GRP, by=ans][, ans[1L], by=id]$V1
# [1] 1 2 3 1 1 4
```

Answer (score 0):

Here's a probably unefficient answer, since it has nested `for`s and two `if`s. It does work though, so it might be a start point for you or someone else.

```
test <- list(1:4,5,8,1,2:3,10)
ids <- 1

for (i in 2:length(test)) {     # start at second because next loop is backwards
  for (j in (i-1):1) {          # will match against previous items
    if (any(test[[j]] %in% test[[i]])) { # checks if there's any match between list items
      ids <- c(ids, ids[j])     # repeat the matched id
      break                     # leaves the loop if a match is found
    }
  }
  if (length(ids) < i) {        # if didn't match before
    ids <- c(ids, max(ids) + 1) # creates a new id from the last
  }
}
ids
# [1] 1 2 3 1 1 4
```

I also suggest to run this on a larger test sample or part of your real data, since the example is quite small and I could have missed something.

Comment: Thanks Molx!  I'll give it a try.  If anyone has a vectorized approach, it would be greatly appreciated.  I suspect using nested for loops will take forever with my large list